# linux spanish special character issue

Tags: linux, editor, special-characters, vi

I have a file which contains spanish characters in Linux which gets displayed correctly while using cat but shows different characters in vi editor.

original text: `GAÑÜ¿KEÑNÉ`

in VI its displayed as `GAÃÃÂ¿KEÃNÃ`

Locale settings:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Because of this, the file does not get loaded properly. Why does this happen?

Comment: can you add the output of `file filename.txt` to your question? And, if possible, the encoding which vi detects.

Comment: @mnme This is the output of file command> file spnchar.dat
spnchar.dat: ISO-8859 text, with very long lines

Comment: what's the text encoding?

Comment: @Oleksandr Kravchuk - utf-8

Comment: @sudha how do you know? Please post output of `od -c filename.txt`